# window.open when ajax call end, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, window.open

i'm doing and Ajax call to send parameters to one .php file, when the call is done, i want to popup a new window to the results page, but it doesn't work.

here is my ajax code

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pipeline2.php",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            //async: false,
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#resultados_pipeline").append(data);
            document.getElementById('Running').style.display = 'none';
            window.open("results_page.php?jid="+job_id);
            alert(job_id);
        });
```

i first think that maybe the job_id is not set in ajax, but the alert show me the expected...

i also tried with the async: true, and it doesn't work either

Comment: Do you get any errors? And I don't see job_id being set...?

Comment: Where are you getting `job_id` from ?

Comment: @LittleBigBot    the jobId is set when i click the submit button, this is working ok, the script pipeline2.php creates the work dir, and run the pipeline, then when is done it alert the jobId and is OK... everithing works fine, it's just that the window with the results don't open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers don't allow `window.open` calls except when involved from a *user* triggered event.

An Ajax response event is not something triggered by the user, so popups are blocked at that point.

Comment: so what can i use instead to open a new window at this point?

Comment: `location = ...`, a dynamically generated `div`, frames.

Comment: It seems only certain user triggered events allow this, for example mouse clicks but not hover events.  Did your previous comment intend to indicate 3 workarounds, or just to suggest some possible alternatives to opening a new window?